# error: pathspec '.....' did not match any file(s) known to git ON LOCAL REPO

Tags: git, local

I know that this question has been asked many times, but I got this error simply by initializing a new repository. No remote branches. I’m just trying to create a new branch.
All my commands
I repeat NO REMOTE BRANCHES. My repo doesn't have any connection with another world.
I create new directory , came into that, did

```
git init
git add .
git commit -m something
# I trying
git checkout -m new_branch
# and I get :
error: pathspec '.....' did not match any file(s) known to git
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you want `git checkout -b new_branch`, to create a new branch from the current head. `-m` is a valid option, but in `git checkout -m new_branch` the `new_branch` should be an existing one. If it does not exist yet, it raises `error: pathspec 'new_branch' did not match any file(s) known to git`

Comment: `git checkout -m` can also be used to re-create a merge conflict, and in this case that's the code path it went down to get the error message. Had the file been a valid name there would have been no merge conflict to re-create, probably. :-)

Comment: Exactly! Just when I was googling I encounter the  problem  have with the remote branches of repo. Thank you.